# Скомпилировать программу из другой программы WinForms

Tags: winforms, компиляция, c++-cli

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть главная программа с GUI, с ней в папке есть папка res, в которой два файла: func.h, в котором программируют функцию и alg.cpp, который минимизирует функцию и возвращает результат. Открывать файл я научился, теперь хотелось бы скомпилировать alg.cpp в .exe, чтобы его затем использовать. Есть ли какой-то простой способ это сделать?

```
private: System::Void задатьФункциюToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    String^ Path = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
    Path += "\\res\\func.cpp";
    try {
        Process::Start("notepad.exe", Path);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception^ ex) {
        MessageBox::Show("Ошибка открытия файла!");
    }
}
```

P.S. так же хотелось бы научиться проверять, когда пользователь закончил редактировать файл и тогда запускать компиляцию.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как минимум, вам придется таскать с собой компилятор и вызывать его.

Comment: @gbg, То есть, условно, установить тот же gcc и запускать его так же, как я уже запускал блокнот?

Comment: Это один из вариантов. Я бы лично взял Tensorflow 2 (он и компилировать умеет, и минимизировать) и свалил бы всю эту работу на него, но все зависит от масштабов бедствия.

Comment: @gbg, не, такого серьёзного решения не нужно, что-нибудь попроще, обычная курсовая

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так: установил себе gcc, а затем запускал его через командную строку

```
system((char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi("g++ " + Path + "\\alg.cpp -o "+ Path+"\\f.exe"));
```

Path - путь к папке с исходниками. Единственный минус - я так и не понял, как бы отловить ошибки, которые могут произойти при компиляции